# The probability of no one winning the powerball jackpot

Tags: probability

The probability of winning the powerball jackpot on any one ticket is well known and easily computed.  How can the probability of no one winning in a given draw be accurately computed when millions of tickets have been purchased and the equation is something like (292,000,000 - 1) / 292,000,000 to the power (the number of tickets sold).  This is a question about how to maintain the accuracy of such a calculation - even with computers

Answer (score 5):

According to an article, only 371 million tickets are considered for the drawing.

So the probability of nobody winning the PowerBall is surprisingly "high":
$$\left(\dfrac{292000000-1}{292000000}\right)^{371000000}\approx0.2807$$

Addressing your question about the accuracy of such a calculation, I am not a programmer so I don't know what algorithms computers use to calculate exponents. However, every natural number can be represented as a sum of distinct powers of 2, so I would assume that it's not that hard to calculate these huge exponents. (Multiplication is very simple on calculators)

For example, to get from $\left(\dfrac{292000000-1}{292000000}\right)^{371000000}$ to $\left(\dfrac{292000000-1}{292000000}\right)^{2\cdot 371000000}$, you just have to square $\left(\dfrac{292000000-1}{292000000}\right)^{371000000}$